# dual boot two hard drives

Tags: dual-boot

I have two separate ssd drives on my computer. I would like to be able to have an option of dual boot in the grub menu at start up. At present ubunf8tu is the boot. My option to boot into openelect is two restart, and quickly select ctrl + f8 combination at start up. This allows me to select the drive from the bios menu at start up. Is this possible, how? Any help is valued.

/dev/sda1 ubuntu 12.04 lts

/dev/sdb1 openelect

Answer (score 0):

Just install GRUB from your Ubuntu:

1. `sudo update-grub`
2. `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`

In this case GRUB is installed to /dev/sda which is what your computer seems to boot automatically.

Comment: Hi fsmaxb. I have install grub on my /dev/sda. When i start up my computer it just boots into ubuntu. What i want is to have the grub menu at start up with the options of booting into /dev/sda or /dev/sdb. I am a newbie, and have just started to read up on the grub.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't expect this to not work as it works for me. When I was using update-grub even systems on an attached usb hard drive where listed and added to the boot menu. Maybe openELEC isn't detected by grub-mkconfig. Can you list the content of /boot/ in openELEC and /etc/lsb-release in openELEC?