# Ubuntu installing bootloader on wrong SSD?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, uefi, bootloader

I'm experiencing a very strange issue. I have a new system, with two drives:

- A samsung 970 plus m.2 SSD
- A samgung 860 evo regular SSD

I've installed windows on the samsung 970 drive. And I wanted to install Ubuntu on the samsung 860 drive. I did this, with a flash-drive Ubuntu 18.04.4 installation, with MBR  as partition scheme.

However, when I use an MBR partition scheme I need to enable CSM (compatability support mode) in my UEFI BIOS, every time I want to boot Ubuntu.So I tought; let's reinstall ubuntu, but with a GPT partition scheme, so I do not need the CSM-mode.

When I launch the Ubuntu installer; I can see my drive with windows, and the empty SSD (Sorry for the crappy pictures):

[image: Windows]

[image: Emtpy ssd]

As you can see I created a ext4 Partition table on the /dev/sda device; which corresponds to my samgung 860 SSD. Then, I select /dev/sda (Samsung SSD 860 (500.1GB) As the Device for boot loader installation, and I select the dev/sda1 location in the menu above as the place where to install Ubuntu. Ubuntu then starts installing in the regular way.

Now comes the strange part. When the installer is finished and I reboot my PC, I can only acces Grub **through my samsung 970 ssd**. The bios does not show me the 860 SSD, only an option which says "Ubuntu on samsung 970". When I select that option, I get grub, and I am able to start up Ubuntu. However, Ubuntu does not seem to reside on the 970 drive but in fact on the 860 drive. It seems that only the bootloader is installed on the 970??

**Can anybody explain me what has happened here? Am I making a thinking mistake somewhere?**

I used to prevent these kinds of issues by simply disconnecting the sata-cables of SSD's I was not currently using. But with the new M.2 SSD's (which are deeply embedded in the mainboard, below my graphics card and a heatsink), this is no easy job.

What I would like is two completely seperate systems on two seperate drives.

Comment: Similar cases or posts are here in askubuntu.com. There seems to be a bug which always reads and installs the grub if there are hard disks connected and having efi partitions though you specify where t0 install bootloader..

Comment: That is so strange... The post you link talks about RAID setups btw, my drives are not in RAID.

Comment: You can search in Askubuntu.com for the similar cases.. Rite now i am on mobile.. May link the similar 0nes when I am 0n deskt0p

Comment: Thx for response! Please link me, haven't found similar cases yet.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/276332/739431 https://askubuntu.com/q/1209735/739431 https://askubuntu.com/q/1195682/739431 https://askubuntu.com/q/472669/739431