# How to hide / disable (=completely block access) to NVME SSD? [Ubuntu 20.04.3 amd64 Desktop]

Tags: 20.04, ssd, 64-bit, nvme

I want to install ubuntu on specific NVME SSD drive and I want to make sure that the installer won't have access to the another NVME SSD drive in my laptop. When I first tried the installation, the installer corrupted my Windows Boot partition, even though I carefully selected the correct drive and triple checked it. (Even in the boot partition option.) So I am not trusting it anymore. The best would be a kernel-level solution for this, because it shouldn't do anything at all with the another NVME SSD drive. My BIOS isn't capable of disabling/freezing devices. The solutions for SATA drives didn't work, so please don't flag this as duplicate.

Comment: I did use the manual option and the latest official 64bit LTS iso (20.04) from the official website.

Comment: It's 20.04.3 amd64 desktop, but the iso shouldn't do anything with disabling NVME SSD drives (I think). I just need a command/boot config or anything that helps to achieve this. I carefully selected the correct drive, set up the root partition as ext4, then selected the same drive in the dropdown menu for the install location of the bootloader, however it wrote it on the another drive, corrupting my Windows Boot partition.

Comment: Thank you. I editied the question.

Comment: Can you unplug it?

Comment: I could, but it's a laptop and it's really hard to do. I don't want to spend hours just to disassembly it, if it could be done with a software solution.

Comment: It sounds like you selected the incorrect drive. Unplugging the drive you don't want to be touched will show you the actual drive you have available to install Ubuntu. Even the best of us can make that mistake and it's good practice to learn.
Once you've installed Ubuntu, you can just leave your 2nd drive out of your /etc/fstab configuration and your Windows disk will never be automatically mounted.

Comment: I tried it again and it corrupted my Windows Boot partition again. I carefully read everything, I am 100% sure that this is a critical bug, not sure what causes it and I honestly don't care. I just want a solution that blocks this retarded os from accessing my windows drive. I'm not dumdum, I can count to two and select the correct drive on a GUI. I don't want to remove the another drive as a temporary solution, it's really hard and I need something permament.

Comment: Now I'm 100% sure that this is a bug. It's really sad, they couldn't fix this in 2 years and there is absolutely no warning that the installer will corrupt my devices without any permission. I guess I will just go with a different distro then. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1212035/ubuntu-installing-bootloader-on-wrong-ssd

Comment: Okay. I just wiped every partition on my Windows SSD and now this dumdum OS's installer does what I select on the GUI.